# I have a Matrix that is cacluating % and it works properly for 1 row but not multiples

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, percentage

I have a Matrix that is calculating % and it works properly for 1 row but not multiples. 
Its calculating the individual departments in the row by item number to equal 100 %. 
When using multiple rows it calculates all the rows together for a total of 100%.

This is not what I want. 
I want all rows to act like the first pic with 1 row calculating across the row.

l[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSN2v.png)like this dept 1 dept 2 dept 3 total item 1 71% 14% 14% 100% item 2 50% 25% 25% 100%

Comment: how are you calculating the % for "Total %" column?  Show your expression

Comment: in sql i am calculating the % as the following SUM(B.RDCQTY)over() as SMDSTRDCQTY, SUM(B.RDQTY) over () as SMDSTQTY, RDCQTY/SUM(B.RDCQTY)over() as PER, which gives me the overall total per item and the correct pertentage per item, then in sql i used in the next cte SUM(PER) OVER () AS TTLPER for the total % for that item.

Comment: in ssrs the percentage colum is using =Sum(Fields!PER.Value) and the total% is using =(Fields!TTLPER.Value)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out, so this is how I needed to have my sql SUM(B.RDCQTY) OVER (partition by RDICDE) AS SMDSTRDCQTY and RDCQTY / SUM(B.RDCQTY) OVER (PARTITION BY RDICDE) AS PER and in the last cte SUM(PER) OVER (PARTITION BY RDICDE) AS TTLPER then in SSRS the percentage column as sum(per) and the total % column as =(Fields!TTLPER.Value)  Now the report is calulating properly per row.[fixedpic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oZFs.png)